# How do I find the children of Ajax added content and then perform a function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have html

```
<ul id="main">
   <li id="A100">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li> 
   <li id="A99">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

then I add the following by ajax.

```
<li id="A98">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li> 
   <li id="A97">
             <ul class="slides">
                     <li><img1></li>
                     <li><img2></li>
             </ul>
   </li>
```

So it looks like this

```
 <ul id="main">
       <li id="A100">
                 <ul class="slides">
                         <li><img1></li>
                         <li><img2></li>
                 </ul>
       </li> 
       <li id="A99">
                 <ul class="slides">
                         <li><img1></li>
                         <li><img2></li>
                 </ul>
       </li>
       <li id="A98">
                 <ul class="slides">
                         <li><img1></li>
                         <li><img2></li>
                 </ul>
       </li> 
       <li id="A97">
                 <ul class="slides">
                         <li><img1></li>
                         <li><img2></li>
                 </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

What is the correct syntax to do

```
$("#main").children(with id after ids ending with 99).nextAll.each(function(){
     $(this).something({
       //do stuff.

      });
});
```

I have to use children() and not find(), because I want to do "something" only on level 1 `<li>.`

EDIT:
I will "do something" on. ajax success. (if that helps in understanding the question any better)

**EDIT2**: Thanks for all suggestions. I found this. Even before I do ajax, I "do something" on the existing html. (ie A100, A99)

If I use

```
$("#main li").each(function() 
    { 

        });
```

**it works** as expected, but IF I use

```
 $("#main").children("li").each(function() 
        { 

            });
```

It is **not working**. Whats the difference here? If I know that, I think i can fix the issue at hand.

May be something like this will work? I tried this and did not work, but may be I am doing it wrong?

```
$("#main li[id$='A99']").nextAll().each(function() 
            { 

                });
```

Comment: So you want to find all ids athat are less than A99, ie find A98 and A97?

Comment: @Chausser yes. Better put, all ids after (rather than "less than") A99 in that ul (ie, A98 and A97). Less than is technically correct as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. But I if you are adding them with AJAX and this function is in the `document.ready()` it will not be called on the new elements. You have to call it after they are added.

```
$("#main").children("li[id$='99']").nextAll().each(function(){
    $(this).html("test"); // do something
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cj7Cs/

Comment: This brings up the html correctly in the DOM, but the slide images are not showing. I am calling this after ajax success, and I dont see anything wrong there either. :(

Comment: can you take a look at my EDIT 2 in qn?

Comment: @aVC Your edit 2 should work as expected. I dont know why its not without more information. What exactly are you trying to do for "do something"??

Comment: I am trying to use http://www.basic-slider.com/ on the images, along with ajax loading when user scrolls down. I know, the html in DOM looks ok, but images dont show :(

Comment: @aVC what wrong with just using `$("#main li).each()` if it works

Comment: I have multiple slide shows, as you see from the html. So after ajax, if I call the slider function on all of them, IT is messing up the existing slide shows. thats why i want to do the slide function only on newly added <li>s

Comment: look here.... http://jsfiddle.net/Cj7Cs/1/  This method is working for all of them. Im still confused as to what is going wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39858/discussion-between-kierchon-and-avc)

Comment: @aVC I think I might know the problem actually. Join the chat so i dont have to keep commenting

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jQEf/1/)

```
for ( var i=98; i>40 /* or some thing else */;i--){
    $("li#A"+i).css("background","red"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not entirely sure that the `id` numbers will decrease numerically, you could actively *test* for the format of the `id` (`A00`) *and* that the number is less-than `100`:

```
$('#main > li').filter(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    return (/^A\d{2}$/).test(id) && parseInt(id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''), 10) < 99;
}).each(function(){
    // do whatever, for example:
    this.classList.add('selected');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2bxaA/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Child (`E > F`) combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).
- JavaScript/DOM:

  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
  - [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).
  - [`String.parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: you are a bad teacher according to Einstein because you made things a bit complicated for a 5 year old ;)

Comment: can you help me with EDIT 2 in question?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, assuming the ids will always be in descending order like that.

```
$("#main").find('#A99').nextAll().each(function(){
    //$(this)... will yield A98, A97
});
```